# Slicing along NumPy ndarray axis with varying indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Given a ndarray `ar` of shape `(n, m)` I want to "extract" subsequences along axis 1 of length `k` with `k<m`. In case of a known starting index `start` for the subsequences of length `k` this can be solved with `new_ar = ar[:, start:end]` (or just `start:start+k`).

However, what if I have a list `start_list` and an `end_list` of length `n` (or just the `start_list`, since the length of the subsequence is known anyway), which contains the starting indices (and ending indices) of the subsequences I want to extract? Intuitively I tried `ar[:, start_list:end_list]`, but this throws `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`.

What would be a solution to this problem **without the usage of loops** and leveraging NumPys methods? For my problem the for-loop took 30 mins, but this has to have a NumPy-style 5ms solution since it's just indexing.

**[edit]**: Since the problem is probably better understood with code (thank you for the hints), I'll try to make it more compact what I want and show what I did to solve it with a loop.

I have an ndarray of shape `(40450, 200000)`, representing `40450` signals of length `200000` each. The signals are shifted and I want to align them. So I want to extract subsequences of length say `190000` from each of the `40450` sequences. For this, I have a list `start_list` of length `40450`, containing the starting indices for the subsequences (each of the `40450` subsequences I want to extract has a different starting point in the original sequence of length `200000`).

I can solve this with a for loop (`ar` contains the original sequences, `start_list` the starting indices):

```py
k = 190000
ar_new = np.zeros((40450, k))
for i in range(ar_new.shape[0]):
    ar_new[i] = ar[i, start_list[i]:start_list[i]+k]
```

If e. g. `start_list[0]` is `0`, this means that I need `ar[0, 0:190000]`, if `start_list[10000]` is `1337`, this means I need `ar[10000, 1337:1337+190000]` etc.

But this takes >30 mins for my case and I am sure it can somehow be solved with NumPy built-in methods/some slicing magic.

Comment: share some code so it is easy to understand this.

Comment: Is the length `k` the same for all? If not it is definitely unavoidable to use loops, otherwise you'd get jagged arrays that are not supported by numpy.

Comment: Yes, `k` is constant for all `n` subsequences.

Comment: Could you show your code and a typical example of a list with starting points?

Comment: Added code & an example in my [edit]. Thanks for hinting that I need to be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

After some trials

```
In [14]: a = np.array(range(200000), dtype=float)
    ...: b = np.array(range(200000), dtype=float)
    ...: start, k = 100, 190000

In [15]: %timeit for _ in range(1000): a[:k] = a[s:s+k]
26.4 ms ± 9.04 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit for _ in range(1000): b[:k] = a[s:s+k]
44.8 ms ± 902 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I am thinking ① if you can do without the non-aligned data, overwriting seems FASTER ② at any rate, if the process is contained in RAM, I'd expect to have my results in the range 1÷10 seconds, not 30 minutes ③ if your problem is swapping, overwriting avoids allocating approximately `4*4E4*2E5 ⇒ 32E9` bytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

We can look at the original 2-dimentional array as at a 3-dimentional structure. With help of `as_strided` we can create a 3d-view to the array, where the first dimension is equal to the original one, the second dimension is for iterating over possible starting positions of a subrow, and the third one is for iterating over the values in a subrow:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

# test data
n, m = 5, 10
arr = np.arange(n*m).reshape(n, m)
k = 5
start_list = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]

# main code
n, m = arr.shape
isize = arr.dtype.itemsize
x = 1 + m - k    # a supporting intermediate dimension

assert k < m
assert len(start_list) == n
assert all(0 <= i < x for i in start_list)

# create a view to the original data with modified shape and strides
arr_modified = as_strided(arr, shape=(n,x,k), strides=(m*isize, isize, isize))

# from each row in arr select a k-length part 
# starting from the corresponding item in start_list
arr_new = arr_modified[range(n), start_list]
```

See also:

- [about as_strided](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)
- [about advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)